# Which alien destroys Old New York?

Tags: futurama

In the first episode, whilst Fry is in the cryo-tube, we see New York is destroyed (several?) times. Which aliens were these? Or do we not know due to records being destroyed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [first destruction of New York City](http://theinfosphere.org/First_Destruction_of_New_York_City) is attributed to none other than Bender, as shown in ["Bender's Big Score"](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Big_Score). After stealing the Nobel Peace Prize, Bender is chased in a ship by the Swedish Air Force above New York. He makes multiple copies of his ship, and ends up destroying the city below in the ensuing fight.

After the city is rebuilt ([all medieval-like](http://theinfosphere.org/Second_Middle_Ages)), it is [destroyed again](http://theinfosphere.org/Second_Destruction_of_New_York_City). It's not clear who was responsible for this second destruction, but the ships look exactly the same as the ones Bender used the first time.

Answer (score -1):

The destruction of Old New York belongs to Bender in Bender's Big Score. Bender is going to the cellar under Planet Express after stealing the Nobel Prize. The army begins to chase after him, so he duplicates the ship and decides to start destroying the city for no reason other than the fun of death. Then, he does this again in the new medieval era that is built from Old New York, then we reach the present day. Technically, because of the medieval castles, Old New York is really Old Old New York, and New New York is really New New New York because the castle was pretty much New Old New York.

Comment: This is the same answer as the one above, why is yours needed? We strive for complete and very accurate answer here. If you answer this better than Gnovice did, we'll up vote.